# jQuery FlexSlider V2.0 issue in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, flexslider

I'm using Flexslider bur the issue is Next/Prev. buttons are not function properly in IE. Where Mozilla works as per expected.

I am dynamically binding Images to FlexSlider (MVC3.0).

FlexSlider : jQuery FlexSlider v2.0(http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)

Below is the code to Launch the Slider:

```
 $jq(window).load(function() {
    $jq('.alternate-images').flexslider({
        slideshow:false,
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 61,
        itemMargin:5,
        controlsContainer:".alternate-images",
        controlNav:false,
        mousewheel:true,
        move:2,
        animationDuration: 0,
        directionNav: true,
        added:function(){
            slideCheck();
            },
        removed:function(){
            slideCheck();
            }
    });
});
```

Any ideas to overcome the issue in IE ?

Thank You

Comment: I've also checked on their official forum. but not able to find the exact solution.